# for comprehension with futures in scala translation to flatMap

Tags: scala, scala-2.9

I have been looking at this [How are Scala Futures chained together with flatMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14394584/how-are-scala-futures-chained-together-with-flatmap) and the corresponding article as well on translating for comprehension.  I am slowly adding stuff to my for comprehension and am stuck as I guess the code I thought would translate to is not correct.

Here I have a runProgram and runProgram2 which I thought would be equivalent and are not because runProgram2 does not compile.  Can someone explain the equiavalent of this for comprehension...

NOTE: yes I know that future.flatMap is typically for collapsing Future[Future[String]] but this is a trimmed down version of my file(perhaps I trimmed it down too far).

```
def main(args: Array[String]) = {
  val future1: Future[String] = runMyProgram()

  //val future2: Future[String] = runMyProgram2()

}

def runMyProgram() : Future[String] = {
  val future = serviceCall()
  future.flatMap(processAllReturnCodes)
}

//    def runMyProgram2() : Future[String] = {
//      val future = serviceCall()
//      for {
//        result <-  future
//      } yield processAllReturnCodes(result)
//    }

def processAllReturnCodes(count: Int) : Future[String] = {

  val promise = Promise.successful("done")
  promise.future
}

def serviceCall() : Future[Int] = {
  val promise = Promise.successful(5)
  promise.future
}

def serviceCall2() : Future[String] = {
  val promise = Promise.successful("hithere")
  promise.future
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `for` comprehension:

```
for {
  result <-  future
} yield processAllReturnCodes(result)
```

Is being translated to this:

```
val t: Future[Future[String]] = future.map(result => processAllReturnCodes(result))
```

Comprehension is really only syntactic sugar for `map` and `flatMap`, with `flatMap` you can *flatten* the future nesting:

```
val u: Future[String] = future.flatMap(result => processAllReturnCodes(result))
```

The difference lies in the signatures:

```
def map[S](f: T => S)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[S]
```

So `map` takes a function form `T` to `S` and wraps the `S` in a future, the problem is that here your `S` is a `Future[String]` which is wrapped in another future giving `Future[Future[String]]`, `flatMap` instead:

```
 def flatMap[S](f: T => Future[S])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[S]
```

Takes a function from `T` to `Future[S]` and returns that future, in your case your method already returns a future and it's a valid parameter for `flatMap`.